# Double Integral and Change of Variable: Find Region

Tags: multiple-integral, change-of-variable

I need to find a region $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that the following equailty holds for any pair of integrable functions $f, g$:

$\iint_D f(x+y) g(x-y)dx dy = \int_0^1f(u) du \cdot  \int_0^1 g(v) dv$

My first thought was to define $T(x, y) = (x+y, x-y)$. But that has $|\det(DT)| = 2$, so the equality doesn't hold.

Is that the correct path? Is there any other $T$ that I am not seeing? Can I do something with the region generated by $T^-1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substitution is -- no question about that --:

$$u=x+y, \ v=x-y.$$

Then

$$x=\frac{u+v}2, \ y=\frac{u-v}2.$$
So, the Jacobian determinant is

$$\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac12&\ \ \ \frac12\\
\frac12&-\frac12\end{vmatrix}=-\frac12.$$

That is, the absolute value of the Jacobian is $\frac12$.

So, the the original requirement cannot be met.

As far as the domain of integration:

[image]
That is,

$$D=\{(x,y):-x \le y\le -x+1 \}\cap\{(x,y):x-1\le y\le x\}.$$

Over this domain

$$0\le x+y=u \le 1 \text{ and } 0\le x-y=v \le 1.$$

Finally, for any integrable $f$ and $g$

$$\int_Df(x+y)g(x-y)\ dxdy=\frac12\int_0^1f(u)\ du\cdot\int_0^1g(v) \ dv.$$